# How to pass "–kubelet-extra-args" to AWS EKS node group created by Terraform aws_eks_node_group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I'm following the example for creating an EKS managed node group from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cni-increase-ip-addresses.html

The configuration requires me to pass additional arguments to the `/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh` script via the `--kubelet-extra-args` argument.

My EKS worker nodes are configured via a Terraform resource [`aws_eks_node_group`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group)

I can't find any option for configuring the resource that would allow me to pass the `--kubelet-extra-args` arguments.

Am I looking at the wrong place or is there no way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried the method in the documentation you linked to by passing `user_data` into the launch template for the ASG for the EKS node group? The `aws_eks_node_group` resource has a `launch_template` block enabling targeting your custom `launch_template` resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group#launch_template-configuration-block.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to pass the `--kubelet-extra-args` you have the option of passing user data to the instance that can be used to perform common automated configuration tasks and even run scripts after the instance starts.

In my point of view, you should have a tpl (template) file with the script you will need to run when the node is created.

userdata.tpl file like [this](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-eks-node-group/blob/61ac9304b3f4e7383639fdca4712a4580535f461/userdata.tpl#L17)

```
#!/bin/bash
%{ if length(kubelet_extra_args) > 0 }
export KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS="${kubelet_extra_args}"
%{ endif }
%{ if length(kubelet_extra_args) > 0 || length (bootstrap_extra_args) > 0 || length (after_cluster_joining_userdata) > 0 }

/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh --apiserver-endpoint '${cluster_endpoint}' --b64-cluster-ca '${certificate_authority_data}' ${bootstrap_extra_args} '${cluster_name}'
```

The previous userdata.tpl file was called using a [templatefile](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-eks-node-group/blob/61ac9304b3f4e7383639fdca4712a4580535f461/userdata.tf#L51) function that renders all the values on the script.

In another file you gonna have, for instance, a resource called `aws_launch_template` or `aws_launch_configuration` that includes an user_data `base64encode` input like [this](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-eks-node-group/blob/813c88fdc18f10026c8b4fc85b386af2df67e1e0/launch-template.tf#L108).

Finally, apply all the changes and then create new nodes, they will be created with the new configuration.

Complete EKS node groups implementation [here](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-eks-node-group) and an example of how to deploy it [here](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-eks-node-group/tree/master/examples/complete)

I hope it may useful for you.

Comment: Alright, I had hoped to avoid setting up a separate launch template but it looks like that's the only way.

Comment: Hey @ChristianSeifert, yes I think is the only way, though, isn't a bad solution, I hope it works for you and your team, let me know if I can clarify any doubt

Answer (score 0):

`--kubelet-extra args` needs to be passed to the `bootstrap.sh` script. When `ami_type` is not "CUSTOM", EKS generates the bootstrap command and appends it at the end of the user-data, which makes it hard to customise there.

It can be done without a custom AMI (but with a launch template) with this in the user-data script. (see [this answer for more details on the user-data script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68895294/1837991))

```bash
# We add another variable the we control to pass even more stuff to kubelet
sed -i '/KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS$/{s|$| \\|;a\ \ \ \ $KUBELET_CUSTOM_ARGS'$'\n''}' /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service /etc/eks/containerd/kubelet-containerd.service
cat > /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/40-kubelet-custom-args.conf <<'EOF'
[Service]
Environment='KUBELET_CUSTOM_ARGS=--allowed-unsafe-sysctls "net.core.somaxconn"'
EOF
```

This uses sed on the unit file to another variable that is passed to kubelet `KUBELET_CUSTOM_ARGS` (since EKS fills in several things, like the max-pods in `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS` and I don't want to override those)

The actual parameters that you want to pass to kubelet will likely differ.

I see the recommendation against calling the bootstrap.sh from the user-data when not using a custom AMI has been removed - it would likely call it before the AWS generated command, so that would work as well, I prefer to let EKS control the parameters.